# How to manually specify language of a fenced code block in Teams?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, syntax-highlighting, stacks-editor

I am just getting started with Stack Overflow for Teams and the editor seems to be different. I type 3 backticks and a code block is automatically created, but the backticks disappear and I can't specify a language for syntax highlighting.

The only option seems to be to let it detect the language. How do I get the code blocks to retain the backticks so I can manually specify the language?

My editor does not have the curly brackets symbol:

[image]

When I type 3 backticks, I get this empty code block and cannot specify the language.

[image]

Comment: The problem with that answer, @cigien , is that it assumes the "old" editor. In teams you are forced to suffer the "new" editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the  "Markdown" switch in the right. Tap that and you'll see the markdown code, including the back ticks for the code fence and be able to add a hinted language.